# HMAC-SHA-512 debug warning in .Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I'm working on a .Net 3.5 WebForms application and this morning I noticed this message in my debug window:

> This application is using the
> HMAC-SHA-384 or HMAC-SHA-512 keyed
> hash algorithm.  The implementation of
> these algorithms were updated in
> service pack 1 of .NET Framework 2.0
> and by default do not produce results
> consistent with the unserviced
> versions of the classes. For more
> information about the changes to the
> algorithms and how to disable this
> warning message please see the release
> notes for service pack
> 1.'WebDev.WebServer20.EXE' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'Anonymously
> Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shawnfa/please-do-not-use-the-net-2-0-hmacsha512-and-hmacsha384-classes) is the only reference I can kind to this kind of message is in reference to .Net 2.0 (without a service pack). Since I'm working on .Net 3.5 I'm assuming that that particular bug has now been fixed.

I'm unsure of how long this message has been appearing in my debug window and have no idea if it's a real problem, or if I can just ignore it.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Yes I'm using .Net 3.5 SP1, I also have these other versions of .Net .NET 1.1 SP 1
.NET 2.0 SP 2
.NET 3.0 SP 2
.NET 3.5 SP 1
.NET 4.0 Client
.NET 4.0 Full

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the text and the blog post, you are save on all frameworks starting with 2.0 SP 1. Hashes made by earlier frameworks will yield the same results as .net 2.0 SP1 (or later), or any other implementation out there.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought, it just surprised me that later versions that are supposed to be fixed still show the warning. Not exactly a helpful debug message.

Comment: @ilivewithian: it's not like they could put the message into 2.0.